# How to save audio file in Django by overriding save method?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save audio file in my Django model by overriding save method. In my save method I am converting the text in audio using (*Google Text to Speech*) library. Here is the link to that Python Library [GTTS](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/)

Here is my code:-

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word_vocab = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        audio = gTTS(text=self.word_vocab, lang='en', slow=True)
        audio.save(self.word_vocab + ".mp3")
        self.audio.save(self.word_vocab + ".mp3", audio)
        super(Word, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can see that my audio file is getting created in Project's root folder but while saving it on the models audio field it's giving me the following error.

`AttributeError: 'gTTS' object has no attribute 'read'`

I have also tried using ContentFile like this

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
```

In models save method:-

```
self.audio.save(self.word_vocab + ".mp3", ContentFile(audio)
```

But over here also I get the error:-

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'gTTS'
```

So I tried to convert it into bytes object:-

```
self.audio.save(self.word_vocab + ".mp3", ContentFile(bytes(audio)))
```

But still I ran into the following Error:-

```
TypeError: 'gTTS' object is not iterable
```

Also I would like to know if there is any other method to save the audio file for the corresponding text value like in our case "word" without having to save the audio file and then assign it to the model's audio field. I would like to directly save it to the models audio field.

 Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you to change your field specific processing inside **save** to a custom field, extending from `FileField`. The problem is that you're trying to save a gTTS's instance. Try the following code:

```
import tempfile

from django.core.files import File
from django.db import models


class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        audio = gTTS(text=self.word_vocab, lang='en', slow=True)

        with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w') as f:
            audio.write_to_fp(f)
            file_name = '{}.mp3'.format(self.word_vocab)
            self.audio.save(file_name, File(file=f))

        super(Word, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The function `audio.save(self.word_vocab + ".mp3")` won't work in your use case, you must use `write_to_fp` or open the file created by this method, as pointed in doccumentation. I hope it helps.

Comment: It's giving me an syntax error for your code at file_name = f'{self.word_vocab}.mp3'

Comment: I've edited the code to be python2 compliant. Can you try again?